# I can't create an Attestation Key (AK) using as its parent an existing Endorsement Key (EK)

Tags: c++, tpm, attestations, key-attestation, tss.msr

I'm using [TSS.MSR](https://github.com/microsoft/TSS.MSR) library for C++ (TSS.CPP). My goal is to generate a new AK from an existing EK that I'm reading using `tpm.ReadPublic()` command.

If I create an EK by myself using `tpm.CreatePrimary()`, without any auth or policy, I'm able to create an AK using `tpm.Create()` passing the ekHandle that I created. But when I use an already existing EK instead of my generated key the `tpm.Create()` command fails.

The EK is at index 0x81010001 and it is with a authPolicy set. The authPolicy is:

```
0x83, 0x71, 0x97, 0x67, 0x44, 0x84,
0xB3, 0xF8, 0x1A, 0x90, 0xCC, 0x8D,
0x46, 0xA5, 0xD7, 0x24, 0xFD, 0x52,
0xD7, 0x6E, 0x06, 0x52, 0x0B, 0x64,
0xF2, 0xA1, 0xDA, 0x1B, 0x33, 0x14,
0x69, 0xAA
```

This is the same as in table *B.3.3 Template L-1: RSA 2048 (Storage)* of [TCG Credential Profile EK 2.0](https://trustedcomputinggroup.org/wp-content/uploads/EK-Credential-Profile-For-TPM-Family-2.0-Level-0-V2.5-R1.0_28March2022.pdf) document.

I think that the problem is related to sessions and policies, since with an EK without any auth set I can generate the AK properly.

Can anyone help me with that?

I tried to start a session using `auto sess = tpm.StartAuthSession(TpmCpp::TPM_SE::POLICY, TpmCpp::TPM_ALG_ID::SHA256)`, then use `tpm.PolicyAuthValue(sess)`, and finally pass the `sess` to the `tpm._Sessions()` but it didn't work. The error message is POLICY_FAIL.